# Why do my tables no longer work on backgrounds?

Tags: html, css, html-table

So something tricky is happening with my tables. I use examples and look up online, for some reason my table styles just don't work. Usually when I do it solo on a white website, it works, once I attempt to put it on a website with background, it no longer works for some reason. So here are the codes, I put the css folder as a style code on the same html folder in this code. I have it on another linked css style sheet. Any help helps greatly! Thanks.

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-image: url(giftpaper.jpg);
}

nav {
    width: 100%;
    background: black;
    overflow: auto;
}

ul {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0 0 0 350px;
    list-style: none;
}

li {
    float: left;
}

.logo img {
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 15px;
    margin-left: 10px;
}

nav a {
    width: 150px;
    display: block;
    padding: 20px 15px;
    text-decoration: none;
    front-family: Arial;
    color: #f2f2f2;
    text-align: center;

}

nav a:hover {
    background: green;
    transition: 0.5s;
}

#text {
    color: aliceblue;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: overline;
    font-size: 50px;
    border: 10px;
    border-color: azure;
}

table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 100%;
}

th,
td {
    padding: 8px;
    text-align: left;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
}

tr:hover {
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
}
```

```html
<div class="logo">
  <a href="ducktopia.html"
    ><img src="the%20logo%20(1).png" width="200" height="40" />
  </a>
</div>
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="ducktopia2.html">News</a></li>
    <li><a href="ducktopia3.html">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="ducktopia4.html">Community</a></li>
    <li><a href="ducktopia5.html">Support</a></li>
    <li><a href="ducktopia6.html">Merchandise</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>

<br />
<h1>
  <div id="text">
    <p>
      In here you can contact our support and request help on major buggs or if
      you suspect dangerous activity on the website, please do not abuse given
      data, and waste our command's time as we take each problem seriously,
      Thank you!
    </p>
    <br />
    <p>
      Here's a table of our team and their position if you desire to contact
      them privately, once again, we kindly ask to not waste their's and your's
      private time off.
    </p>
    <br />
    <table id="customers">
      <tr>
        <th>Position</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Contact</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Main Dev/Manager</td>
        <td>Darija Galdikaitė</td>
        <td>darijagaldikaite@gmail.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Server controller</td>
        <td>Christina Berglund</td>
        <td>ser.chisti@yan.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Developer</td>
        <td>Francisco Chang</td>
        <td>fracg@gmail.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Developer</td>
        <td>Roland Mendel</td>
        <td>rolandmend@gmail.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Admin server runner</td>
        <td>Helen Bennett</td>
        <td>HelBenn@gmail.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Live Helper/Dev</td>
        <td>Philip Cramer</td>
        <td>philips@yahoo.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Live Helper/Dev</td>
        <td>Yoshi Tannamuri</td>
        <td>yoyori@gmail.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Liver Helper/Dev</td>
        <td>Giovanni Rovelli</td>
        <td>giovanni322@gmail.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Main debbuger/Dev</td>
        <td>Simon Crowther</td>
        <td>scrowther0@gmail.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Forum Editor</td>
        <td>Marie Bertrand</td>
        <td>bertr321@yahho.com</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</h1>
<br />
<br />

<div id="text">
  Main contacts, used for very important reasons in case of emergencies. Please
  beware, using this for non important reasons and spam, may get you an IP ban.
  Thank you!

  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>Name:</th>
      <td>Pandaripool</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th rowspan="2">Phone numbers:</th>
      <td>86577854</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>86777855</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you maybe show a example of what happends when the background is added? Like a screenshot? Would make it a bit easier to understand the problem.

Comment: Are you using any external css links in your code?

Comment: add an image with desired result.

Comment: Off topic, but it is an error to put divs and tables in a h1.